# Using Jetty Websocket Client API through the javax.websocket API: how to set MaximumMessageSize?

Tags: java, websocket, client, jetty

I'm writing a Java websocket client, using the API provided through javax.websocket. The implementation of those interfaces is provided through Jetty, in particular org.eclipse.jetty.client and related namespaces.

When using Jetty directly (not via using javax.websocket), org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session allows to retrieve a org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketPolicy instance that can be used to set properties as such:

```
session.getPolicy().setMaxBinaryMessageSize(someLong);
```

I have not found a way to set these properties when using Jetty's implementation through javax.websocket. This is a problem as Jetty sets a default value that acts as an upper ceiling for the supported message sizes that can be received on the client.

javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer only allows to set the buffer sizes, not the maximum message sizes. It feels like that interface is missing methods to allow setting the maximum message sizes.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

**Edit:** Setting maximum buffer sizes don't seem to be the same thing as setting maximum message sizes.

For example, using javax.websocket:

```
WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
container.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(131072);
```

Jetty will still close the connection on the receiving end for messages smaller than the set buffer size but larger than what seems to be the maximum message size:

> Binary message size [69620] exceeds maximum size [65536]

To me, this is clear indication that Jetty treats DefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize as a different property than DefaultMaxBinaryMessageSize.

thanks,

Tobias

Answer (score 0):

JSR356 (`javax.websocket`) allows you to set the max message size via the `@OnMessage` annotations.

```java
package jetty.websocket.dummysockets;

import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;

@ClientEndpoint
public class EchoSocket
{
    @OnMessage(maxMessageSize = 600000)
    public String echo(String msg)
    {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Also, the `javax.websocket.Session` has the buffer size methods you already discovered.

aka:

- [`Session.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html#setMaxTextMessageBufferSize-int-)
- [`Session.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html#setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize-int-)

"Buffer Size" is a bad name IMO.

Buffer Size when applied to ...

- Streaming modes impacts how much memory each buffer allocates for read, and how much it will buffer on writes before automatic flush.
- Whole message deliver modes impacts the overall size of whole message buffer.
- Partial message delivery modes applies to the individual websocket frame message buffer size.

Comment: While this solves the immediate issue or question, annotations have shortcomings in that they do not allow parameter from method calls or even variable instances. Values are hardcoded. Is there no way to set these properties with a proper method call?

Comment: The methods in `javax.websocket.Session` (as outlined in the answer) are the calls you want.  They are just badly named.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, as I tried setting the max buffer size with those methods for binary messages and the Jetty client would still shut down the connection when messages within that buffer size were received.

Comment: I edited the original question and added an example of how the buffer size seems to be different from the message size property (in Jetty).

Comment: Try again, but make sure you are using Jetty 9.4.12.RC2 - I think you might have been bit by issue https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2767

Comment: I'll give that a try!